# combine values in a table so they can be counted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with 5 different records and all have ids:

```
ID       Name
1        New
2        SomeWhatNew
3        KindOfNew
4        Old
5        Dead
```

I need to combine IDs 1,2 and 3(Give those the name New_Results) so I can count them.

So lets say I have Five 1s and Four 2s and One 3 and Six 4s and Two 5s.
So my results would be:

```
Name           Count
New_Results     10
Old             6
Dead             2
```

How can I write a tsql query that would do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 'New_Results'
             else Name
        end) as grp
from t
group by (case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 'New_Results'
               else Name
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN ID IN(1,2,3) THEN 'New_Results'  ELSE NAME END) AS Name,
COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM df1  
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ID IN(1,2,3) THEN 'New_Results'  ELSE NAME END
```

Here is the [fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c321/4)   link.

Answer (score 0):

Though you could use case statements, I've found that they can slow down your query. Try a union if you expect a ton of data or if you just want to compare performance:

Given that your ID and Name columns are in a table called "type_table" and the data is in a table called "results_table" and there is a relation between type_table.id and results_table.type_id:

```
SELECT
  'New_Results' AS Name,
  COUNT( 1 ) AS Count
FROM
  results_table
WHERE
  type_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
UNION
SELECT
  type_table.Name,
  COUNT( 1 ) AS Count
FROM
  results_table
  JOIN type_table
    ON results_table.type_id = type_table.id
WHERE
  type_table.id > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(ID int,Name varchar(40))
insert into @t VALUES
(1,'New'),
(1,'New'),
(1,'New'),
(1,'New'),
(1,'New'),
(2,'SomeWhatNew'),
(2,'SomeWhatNew'),
(2,'SomeWhatNew'),
(2,'SomeWhatNew')
,(3,'KindOfNew')
,(4,'Old')
,(5,'Dead')
,(5,'Dead')
;with CTE as
(
select ID,DENSE_RANK()over( order by id)rn
,case when id in(1,2,3) then 'New_Results' when id=4 then 'Old' else 'Dead' end Name
from @t t1 
)

select 
 count(*),Name
from CTE
group by Name
```